# How to create a AS400 shell script (.ksh) file

Tags: shell, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am new to shell script on iSeries, but i have created one sample script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

cd /QIBM/Userdata/employeedetails/

pwd

ls -ltr
```

I placed it under `/QIBM/testscript.ksh` and tried to run the script on the main menu using `STRQSH CMD('/QIBM/testscript.ksh')`

I got this error, can someone please let me know what did do wrong here?

```
qsh: 001-0014 Command /QIBM/testscript.ksh not found. 

Press ENTER to end terminal session.
```

I am wondering, is it possible to create shell script on the iSeries (AS/400)?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to create a shell script.

The default shell is [Qshell](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahz/rzahzintro.htm) which can be referenced as `/bin/qsh` or `/bin/sh`.

```
echo '#!/bin/sh
pwd
ls -ltr' > $HOME/testscript.sh
```

To run it:

```
STRQSH CMD('$HOME/testscript.sh')
```

Korn shell is available with [IBM PASE for i](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzalf/rzalfintro.htm) at `/qopensys/usr/bin/sh` or `/qopensys/usr/bin/ksh`.

Also I would advise against putting things in the `/QIBM` directory.  I suggest `$HOME` or `/opt`.  See the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make the script executable? Unless you have *ALLOBJ authority, you must mark the script executable by executing either

`chmod 755 /QIBM/testscript.ksh` from a shell or

`CHGAUT OBJ('/QIBM/testscript.ksh') USER(USRNAME) DTAAUT(*RWX)` from CL

It also looks like you maybe forgot the # in the first line, unless it's just a Stack Overflow formatting mistake. Your first line should be:

`#!/QOpenSys/usr/bin/ksh`

as ksh is not found in /bin on IBM i.